# What's the right way of performing several operations on a filesystem at once?

Tags: haskell

Suppose I want to know whether a file exists, and if it's a directory, additionally retrieve its contents. I may go as follows:

```
browseSimple :: FilePath -> IO (Either FilePath [FilePath])
browseSimple x = do
    isAvailable <- doesPathExist x
    if not isAvailable then error $ "File not found: " ++ x else do
        isFile <- doesFileExist x
        if isFile then return $ Left x else do
            isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist x
            if not isDirectory then error $ "Unknown filesystem node: " ++ x else do
                listing <- listDirectory x
                return $ Right ((x </>) <$> listing)
-- ^
-- λ browseSimple  "."
-- Right [..."./Filesystem.hs"...]
```

-- And it kinda works. But I wonder: what would happen if the node gets unlinked along the way, say just before the last "do" block?

I don't know C, but my guess is that all this iffiness would be replaced by 1 (one) POSIX system call: `opendir` will either let me read the directory contents or return a meaningful error I could pattern match against. That's only for POSIX-compliant systems, though.

What is the correct, idiomatic, professional way of doing things like this in Haskell? Do I address it with the stuff from `System.Posix.Files`? What is the state of the art around this?

---

**postscriptum**

I could have just casted `listDirectory`, and pattern matched on the error (as per suggestion from @Ryan), but I am kind of suspicious because it can apparently say `NoSuchThing` in case of both `ENOENT` and `ENOTDIR`. The description is scarce, the behaviour is not spelled out, and I don't want to read any guarantees into it.

Comment: Where’s `listDirectory` from?

Comment: @Ryan From the modern [`directory`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.2.0/docs/System-Directory.html). ("*Since: 1.2.5.0*"!)

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.2.0/docs/System-Directory.html#v:listDirectory – catch `NoSuchThing` and `InappropriateType`?

Comment: `POSIX` in fact can get into a lot of race conditions where an operation a program selects is no longer valid moments later. One example they did something about eventually was how `tmpnam()` returned a valid name for a file that did not already exist—at some point in time, but that wasn’t guaranteed to *still* be valid when you tried to actually create the temporary file. A later version of `POSIX` added a new function that created a temporary file as a single operation.

Comment: @Ryan I am kind of suspicious because it can apparently say `NoSuchThing` in case of both `ENOENT` and `ENOTDIR`. The description is scarce, the behaviour is not spelled out, and I don't want to read any guarantees into it.

Comment: I don’t know that this is The RIght Way, but if you’ve got a sequence of operations that could fail due to a race condition, but it can be restarted if that happens, one elegant solution is to wrap them all in a function that restarts itself and tail-recurses if necessary until if it succeeds. If there’s an unrecoverable error, treat it as an exception.  Or if you need multiple resources at once, but one could otherwise be claimed, that’s what a mutex is for.

Comment: @Davislor I kind of dig that idea of retrying, but it's rather grim and convoluted to write by hand every time, isn't it? And a mistake would be expensive, and testing next to impossible. There should be a library for such things?.. About mutexes, I don't know how to use them at all, short of using them in Haskell.

Comment: A next-best alternative might be a function that returns failure and cleans up if *any* operation fails, so it appears to the rest of the program like a single operation that either succeeds or fails, and it can choose to retry or not. There might or might not be a function in the API to perform several small operations at once, or to lock the resource you need. Check on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: @Kindaro: I don’t have time right now, but I think you should look into exactly when `NoSuchThing` and `InappropriateType` are thrown, contribute appropriate docs back (it may be a platform difference, symlink thing, or docs mistake), and use them. Starting points: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.2.0/docs/src/System-Directory.html#getDirectoryContents, https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.1/docs/src/System.Posix.Directory.html#openDirStream, https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Foreign-C-Error.html#v:throwErrno

Comment: @Ryan It shall be done.

Answer (score 5):

> But I wonder: what would happen if the node gets unlinked along the way, say just before the last "do" block?

You'll get an exception, and that's no big deal in this context.  You are performing IO and can handle it.  I don't think you'll find a fail-proof platform agnostic solution.

How about you make a useful wrapper monad to keep the code readable?  It might be more boilerplate than you like (in which case just wrap the whole function call with `catch`) but for larger portions of code can be quite nice:

```
data MyErr = CaughtException SomeException
                             -- ^ You might want to just catch
                             --   specific types of exceptions here
          | MyErr String

type M = ExceptT MyErr IO

myErr :: String -> M a
myErr = throwE . MyErr

myIO :: IO a -> M a
myIO io = ExceptT (catch (Right <$> io) (pure . Left . CaughtException))
```

The `M` monad allows you to capture all the ugly exceptions along with your program logic and bundle it up into a single `Either` result.  You'd use it as such:

```
browseSimple :: FilePath -> IO (Either MyErr [FilePath])
browseSimple x = runExceptT $ do
    isAvailable <- myIO $ doesPathExist x
    when (not isAvailable) (myErr $ "File not found: " ++ x)
    isFile <- myIO $ doesFileExist x
    when isFile (myErr x)
    isDirectory <- myIO $ doesDirectoryExist x
    when (not isDirectory) (myErr $ "Unknown filesystem node: " ++ x)
    listing <- myIO $ listDirectory x
    return ((x </>) <$> listing)
```

You could enhance things, such as provide `myIO` with more information so if/when things fail you can tie the result to where in your operation things took a nose dive but that's usually overkill.

We could clean things up further with whenM (typed not tested):

```
whenM io m = myIO io >>= \b -> when b m

browseSimple2 :: FilePath -> IO (Either MyErr [FilePath])
browseSimple2 x = runExceptT $ do
    whenM (not <$> doesPathExist x)
          (myErr $ "File not found: " ++ x)
    whenM (doesFileExist x)
          (myErr x)
    whenM (not <$> doesDirectoryExist x)
          (myErr $ "Unknown filesystem node: " ++ x)
    myIO $ (x </>) <$> listDirectory x
```

Comment: Isn't the usual recommendation *not* to do checks before trying to do IO operations, precisely because the state could change between doing the check and doing the operations, and instead just try and catch the error (if any)?

Comment: Yes. However, this is a stack overflow question and I assume it's a simplified version of what they want.  Also checking (at some point) gives you helpful info for error messages to the user.