# What happens if I call FindFirstFile on an erroneous path? Would the error be meaningful?

Tags: c++, haskell, winapi, error-handling, filesystems

In order to obtain a satisfactory answer to [another question nearby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48699422), I am investigating the failure modes of [`System.Directory.getDirectoryContents`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.2.0/docs/src/System-Directory.html#getDirectoryContents) from [`directory`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory) Haskell library. This is a platform agnostic function that compiles to different code on Posix and Windows platforms, that then call platform specific API. My goal is to determine failure modes and errors that I may expect if the path I provide does not allow directory listing.

- It may be a non-existent path.
- It may not be a directory.
- The caller may lack the permissions to obtain a listing.
- There are other failure modes I can think of as well, but I refrain from listing them all here.

The Posix part is clear to me as I have some experience with Linux, and it is actually very straightforward; the error codes that may be raised are all listed in [`man 3 opendir`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-opendir/), and I do not expect any surprises.

The Windows part is not clear to me at all. It is an expensive, closed source operating system, written (apparently?) in `C++` (rather than `C`), with which I am only superficially familiar. Due to its price and rarity, I am not going to lay my hands on a Windows operated computer any time soon, so I need help from my better endowed fellows.

#### My questions:

1. I wish I was at least certain that, if `getDirectoryContents` is to fail for any foreseeable reason (I'm not considering sudden hardware failure), it will fail in the call to `FindFirstFileW`, which is made [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32-2.7.0.0/docs/src/System.Win32.File.html#findFirstFile). Is this the case? That is, can it not also fail in subsequent calls to `FindNextFileW`? I presume not, as the directory entries should be mapped to memory at this point and, while the handle is held open, even the removal of the file in the underlying storage should not destroy them. At least, that is what I would expect from Linux. Does the same thinking apply to Windows? I am suspicious due to, for one, the fact that a search for a glob may be by any measure more complicated than just reading a single entry of a filesystem (which is what a Posix system does through `opendir`).
2. The Haskell wrapper calls `GetLastError` in case `FindFirstFileW` returns a null handle or `FindNextFileW` errors out. How can I find out what error codes may manifest themselves and in what circumstances? I discovered [some official help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) for `FindFirstFile` but I do not think there is any mention of error code values and their meanings there; neither is in the [help for `FindNextFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx).

Overall, I obviously lack the understanding of WinApi and I expect the answers to these questions could be derived from the general understanding of the Windows operating system. Thus, I would enjoy a principled answer, or a correction of my presuppositions, more than an answer that plainly states the facts.

#### Update.

I [asked](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2018-March/028615.html) the maintainers and I had pointed out to me the existence of a [file](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/src/cbits/Win32Utils.c) that contains a table of conversion between Windows and Posix error codes.

Comment: `FindNextFileW` can also fail, an example would be network resource becoming unavailable.

Comment: @RichardCritten Oh. What you imply is that results are searched for one after one? I would appreciate a more extended introduction into the inner workings of `Find...File` functions.

Comment: Windows is not open source AFAIK, thus it is impossible for an end-user / programmer to know exactly what return codes are issued.  Even a Windows update could add additional codes to certain API functions.  You just have to live with `GetLastError` -- it is what it is.

Comment: Have a read of: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060406-13/?p=31633

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. [FindFirstFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418.aspx) and [FindNextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428.aspx) can both fail. The documentation tells you how to distinguish a successful call from reaching the end of the list from a failed call. Asking about anything more is essentially asking about implementation details. Those aren't contractual, nor is there any guarantee, that they will not ever change across versions of Windows.

Comment: @IInspectable What you are saying is very unfortunate. Would it mean that I cannot even know from the error code whether the error is due to permissions, path existence, or the path not being a directory?

Comment: Unless the MSDN page explicitly states a return value, Microsoft does not conciser error code values part of the API contract.

Comment: This seems like one of those edge cases where the only plausible answer is to try it and see for yourself how Windows behaves. My advice is to avoid the assumption it will behave exactly the same between one version of Windows to the next, or even between user permission levels.

Comment: Those API calls cannot reliably report even certain classes of errors. After all, at some point the requests are passed down the file system (or network) stack, and those implementations and the error codes they return are usually not controlled by the team implementing the API.

Comment: *I cannot even know from the error code whether the error is due to permissions, path existence, or the path not being a directory?* - no, we can know this by error code. also much better call `RtlGetLastNtStatus` instead `GetLastError` (frequently `GetLastError` lost sensetive info from original status). despite concrete and possible error values not documented (and this is device depended - as result and can not be documented) usual error status give enough info for understanding source of problem

Comment: Windows is the most popular operating system in the world. To describe it as "rare" is stretching things somewhat.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov -- This has been the framework of Windows API programming for over two decades now.  You call a Windows API function, you get an error code.  If the error code means failure, then you look at the documentation to see if you can get more information by calling `GetLastError` (that is almost always documented).  That is what your Haskell wrapper does.  If there was a better way of figuring out these errors, the writers of that wrapper would have used it, but even they knew that it is pointless to try and enumerate all of the possible return codes.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I dunno. My cheapskate friends use Linux, the rich ones sport a Mac. Both being by and large Posix compliant. Perhaps I have a skewed perspective due to being immersed in hacker / developer circles.